android, RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE does not work in speech to text
Suddenly, my speech to text app which has the following statement does not work. It remains at English(United Kingdom). The language on the dialog box does not changed.
I open source the complete codes.
    intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    Long timeToWait = 20000L;
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 3000);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
 
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, mylanguage);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            mylanguage);
 

    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);

Is it possible there is a bug from Android or miui Global 14.0.1? Is there a  fix?

this happens starting today. 2 phones found fail. The app remains works in some other android phone.

all apps on all my phones now  cannot change  language, only English (united kingdom) is available.
I will wait several days to see if there is problem with google.

It is probably a bug in the recent version of the system app “Speech Recognition & Synthesis”.
The language learning app I am developing is also not working properly.
Can you “uninstall” Speech Recognition & Synthesis from Google Play and revert to the old version so it will work again?

uninstall updates from apps -> speech recogniton and synthesis from Google

Recently our app had a symptom that this time it was only recognized as English.
We tried various things and found that in the above source code, we gave Locale.CHINA.toString() to the parameter “mylanguage”  for EXTRA_LANGUAGE, but this would give “zh_CN”. When I gave “zh-CN” instead, the Japanese Chinese speech was recognized without any problem. In other words, “_” was not allowed, but “-” was required. This change may have been happening since September.

You're attempting to use a key of the Bundle returned by ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS, which does not provide the least meaning. See the documentation of RecognizerIntent, which shows the available options: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent
EXTRA_LANGUAGE_DETECTION_ALLOWED_LANGUAGES and EXTRA_LANGUAGE_SWITCH_ALLOWED_LANGUAGES appear more likely.
